# kivy python: 'Label' object is not callable

Tags: python, kivy

I am watching and following the tutorials of [Tech With Tim on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM) and I have installed kivy, but when I run a simple test program to see if it works I'm getting an error. I don't know how to make it work. Do I need to reinstall kivy?

This is the code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    @property
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='UMIND')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test app.py", line 13, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
 TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable
```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but have you tried without the `@property` as he has in the video?

Comment: Your usage looks pretty much like that in [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html).

Comment: It works, thank you very much for your help  and sorry my English is not that good, again thank you so much